# Pass object variables into eventlistener

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dom-events

While trying to create a mouse listener to canvas object I faced a problem which took me a long time to solve - How can I pass object variables (this.X, this.Y) to an event listener, for example:

```
  function Test() {

  this.canvas = ....

  this.mouseDownHandler = ....

  canvas.addEventLIstener('mousedown', this.mouseDownListener, false);
}
```

So I came up with the following solution

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution the worked for me -

```
function Test() {
     this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
     var self = this;
     this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",
         function(e, param) {
               self.mouseDownHandler(e, param);
          }.bind(null, this), false);
}

Test.prototype.mouseDownHandler = function(t, e) {
    t.ctx.fillRect(e.pageX, e.pageY, 10, 10);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind me slightly simplifying @Yehonatan 's answer:

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("app")
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d")
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", e => this.mouseDownHandler(e))
  }

  mouseDownHandler(e) {
    this.ctx.fillRect(e.pageX, e.pageY, 10, 10)
  }
}

let t = new Test()
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/xej0rstk/1/)